# Retrieve value of Url parameter and autofill form using the corresponding values for that parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have managed to pass a parameter in the url using

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl='<%# "/Private/NewEnquiry.aspx?Id=" + Eval("Id")%>' Text='Update'></asp:HyperLink>
```

How can I be able to use the Id parameter to run `Select * from Tablename where Id=[parameterValue]` and then use these values to autofill the NewEnquiry.aspx page?

I have a script that can actually retrieve the ID but I don't know how to use this retrieved ID to fetch the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 var Id = getUrlVars()["Id"];
 alert(Id);
 function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
        vars[key] = value;
        });
  return vars;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This question is not related to database. please use tags properly

Comment: done! Thought It had got something to do with database too! But its more with Asp.net!

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve data from database? If so what kind of database are you connecting to?

Comment: Yeah. It's a sql database!

Comment: @Anoj it still depends on what database you're working with, like mysql or sql server. If you're referring to sql server. Here's a link you may get some basic ideas for building a db connection. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1038536/Day-Database-Connectivity-ASP-NET-Csharp-with-SQL

Comment: You got it wrong. I want the values from database to populate in the Form fields in reference to the ID parameter that is passed from a different page!